# Map mongodb collection to non existing java class

Tags: java, json, spring, mongodb

I've got a mongodb with several collections and I need to map those collects to new Java classes using spring. First idea was to expect one item as json and to generate the java class based on this json code. Here's the json:

```
{


    "_id" : ObjectId("5550b632e6d665c6fc8b4567"), 
    "id" : NumberInt(1), 
    "registrationDate" : "2008-11-02 10:55:05", 
    "firstname" : "", 
    "lastname" : "", 
    "email" : "mail@mail.nl", 
    "salutation" : "", 
    "enabled" : false, 
    "bounceCount" : NumberInt(0), 
    "groups" : [
        NumberInt(1), 
        NumberInt(15), 
        NumberInt(16), 
        NumberInt(19), 
        NumberInt(20), 
        NumberInt(21), 
        NumberInt(22)
    ], 
    "tags" : [
        NumberInt(1), 
        NumberInt(19), 
        NumberInt(29), 
        NumberInt(34), 
        NumberInt(49), 
        NumberInt(51), 
        NumberInt(68), 
        NumberInt(89), 
        NumberInt(547), 
        NumberInt(568), 
        NumberInt(569), 
        NumberInt(571)
    ], 
    "identifier" : "s47FOeqYzUt7xENFKPIkZwKc5LtrYrcL", 
    "orders" : [
        {
            "langIndependentId" : NumberInt(39), 
            "orderDate" : NumberInt(1279584917), 
            "updatePeriod" : NumberInt(1342821599), 
            "amounteur" : NumberInt(1989)
        }, 
        {
            "langIndependentId" : NumberInt(41), 
            "orderDate" : NumberInt(1279623009), 
            "updatePeriod" : NumberInt(1405893599), 
            "amounteur" : NumberInt(990)
        }
    ], 
    "lang" : "", 
    "langs" : null, 
    "hitlist" : NumberInt(0), 
    "country" : "", 
    "insertDate" : ISODate("2006-11-02T10:55:05.000+0000"), 
    "updateDate" : ISODate("2007-02-03T10:37:05.189+0000"), 
    "insert_date" : NumberInt(1431352882), 
    "update_date" : NumberInt(1435141711)
}
```

First of all, no tool is able to generate according java classes, as items like "NumberInt" or "ISODate" are not known... I just removed those terms and adjusted my javacode, but it is not possible to query my mongodb and parse the result to java classes by using the springframework....

If I create a new class and insert this new class to a collection, everything is fine...
Any idea for this?

Comment: if you are searching for document object mapper then check  https://mongodb.github.io/morphia/  and http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-mongodb/

Answer (score 0):

Try the @Transient annotation to "hide" those attributes, if they are not needed. See http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-document/docs/current/reference/html/#mapping-usage-annotations